# "Uncaught TypeError: bgColor is not a function" in HTML select onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML switch with an onchange tag that should run the JavaScript function `bgColor` with the argument `this` but whenever I try using this, it gives me an error: `Uncaught TypeError: bgColor is not a function`. Any ideas?

HTML

```
<select id="selectBgColor" onchange="bgColor(this)">
    <option value="blue" selected>Blue</option>
    <option value="gray">Gray</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
// The following is for changing graph color
var graphColor = "blue";
var graphBgColor = "rgba(106, 154, 177, 0.3)";
var graphBorderColor = "rgb(99, 121, 132)";
function bgColor(s) {
    graphColor = $(s).val();
    graphBgColor = graphColor == "blue" ? "rgba(106, 154, 177, 0.3)" : "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3)";
    graphBorderColor = graphColor == "blue" ? "rgb(99, 121, 132)" : "rgb(0, 0, 255)";
    update_temp_and_time();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How is the javascript being included in the page?

Comment: @evolutionxbox It's using <script>, the provided code is only part of the code, not the whole thing.

Comment: Did you try just changing the name of the function, seeing as there already is a [global gbColor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/bgColor) property

Comment: @adeneo: Which would be fine (as it's on `document`, not a global), but there's also the `bgColor` on elements, and the weird environment in which `onxyz`-attribute style event handlers runs puts the one on the element in scope...

Comment: @adeneo Yeah, I just did after someone said that in an answer and it worked.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - oh, that's right, it's the document, not the window. I only remembered the "global" one that changes the background on "everything", and the one on tables, which I've actually used. Can't remember ever using it on any other element. In chrome though -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/0bhLwvag/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a different name for the function. The environment in which `onxyz`-attribute style event handler code is run has several `with` clauses (effectively) putting all properties of the element (and some other things) in scope*, with precedence over globals. There's an old, no-longer-standard property called `bgColor` on elements which is getting in the way of your global function.

Another name (like `setBackgroundColor`) will work:

```js
// The following is for changing graph color
var graphColor = "blue";
var graphBgColor = "rgba(106, 154, 177, 0.3)";
var graphBorderColor = "rgb(99, 121, 132)";
function setBackgroundColor(s) {
    graphColor = $(s).val();
    graphBgColor = graphColor == "blue" ? "rgba(106, 154, 177, 0.3)" : "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3)";
    graphBorderColor = graphColor == "blue" ? "rgb(99, 121, 132)" : "rgb(0, 0, 255)";
    update_temp_and_time();
}
function update_temp_and_time() {
  console.log("graphColor = " + graphColor);
}
```

```html
<select id="selectBgColor" onchange="setBackgroundColor(this)">
    <option value="blue" selected>Blue</option>
    <option value="gray">Gray</option>
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

* This is one of the *many* reasons not to use `onxyz`-attribute style event handlers, and not to use globals. Instead, ensure your code is not at global scope (for instance, wrap it in a scoping function) and hook up your handlers dynamically.

E.g.:

```js
// Scoping function
(function() {
  // The following is for changing graph color
  var graphColor = "blue";
  var graphBgColor = "rgba(106, 154, 177, 0.3)";
  var graphBorderColor = "rgb(99, 121, 132)";

  $("#selectBgColor").on("change", function() {
      graphColor = $(this).val();
      graphBgColor = graphColor == "blue" ? "rgba(106, 154, 177, 0.3)" : "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3)";
      graphBorderColor = graphColor == "blue" ? "rgb(99, 121, 132)" : "rgb(0, 0, 255)";
      update_temp_and_time();
  });
  
  function update_temp_and_time() {
    console.log("graphColor = " + graphColor);
  }
})();
```

```html
<select id="selectBgColor"">
    <option value="blue" selected>Blue</option>
    <option value="gray">Gray</option>
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```