# How to change button background color by name using Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I have several buttons on my webpage and want to style the background colors when I click on them according to the button's name. I want all the "Toms" to be lightgray, all the "Dicks" to be lightgreen, and all the rest ("Harrys") to be lightyellow. I added the following code to my external Javascript page, but it's not working:

```
    function bgColor() {
      var x = document.getElementsByTagName("button").name;
      if (x == "Tom") {
      document.getElementsByTagName("button").style.backgroundColor=
      "lightgray";
      } else if (x == "Dick") { 
      document.getElementsByTagName("button").style.backgroundColor=
      "lightgreen";
      } else { 
      document.getElementsByTagName("button").style.backgroundColor=
      "lightyellow";           
      }
    }
```

The HTML reads something like this but between less than/greater than symbols, of course:

```
    button type="button" name="Tom" onclick="bgColor()"
    button type="button" name="Dick" onclick="bgColor()"
    button type="button" name="Harry" onclick="bgColor()"
```

**EDITED TO ADD** 
I can't figure out how to reply to Mikkel's comment directly. I tried simply posting another comment, but it wouldn't let me add code. Anyway, I tried the fix that he suggested using the following but it didn't work for me either.

```
    function bgColor() {
      var tom = document.querySelector('button[name="Tom"]')
      .style.backgroundColor = 'lightgray';
      var dick = document.querySelector('button[name="Dick"]')
      .style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
      var harry = document.querySelector('button[name="Harry"]')
      .style.backgroundColor = 'lightyellow';
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mikkel has said, your selector is wrong - You'll want to use an [`attribute selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to get the elements that match your `name` attribute

---

However, in this specfic case as well you've got a more weird issue - You'll have to change the name of your function - `bgColor` is also the name of a property on the elements which I believe is causes your further issues. - [You can read more about that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45062793/uncaught-typeerror-bgcolor-is-not-a-function-in-html-select-onchange)

If you change the name to something like `changeColors` you shouldn't have this issue

As an aside, there's no need to assign your querySelectors to a variable, you can just run them in this case

```js
function changeColors() {
  document.querySelector('button[name="Tom"]').style.backgroundColor = 'lightgray';
  document.querySelector('button[name="Dick"]').style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
  document.querySelector('button[name="Harry"]').style.backgroundColor = 'lightyellow';
}
```

```html
<button type="button" name="Tom" onclick="changeColors()"> X </button>
<button type="button" name="Dick" onclick="changeColors()"> X </button>
<button type="button" name="Harry" onclick="changeColors()"> X </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByTaName("button") is getting all your buttons. What you want to do, is check each of the buttons individually and apply the color.

You can do it with the code below, that'll change the color of "Tom". You can repeat it to make it work for your other buttons.

```
function bgColor() {
  var tom = document.querySelector('button[name="Tom"]').style.backgroundColor = 'purple'
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Mikkel. I tried this but it didn't work either. I edited my original question to incorporate the new code you suggested. Do I still have something wrong?

Comment: It's working now! Thanks to everyone for their expertise and their patience.

Comment: No worries - don't forget to mark the solution as the answer :) whether it's Shiny or me that helped solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, using **bgColor** as a user-defined function name will throw a *type error since it's a reserve keyword for JS (Object's property) though deprecated.*

Second ->  **var x = document.getElementsByTagName("button").name;** will obviously throw an error **x is undefined** because this syntax without '**.name**' should return all **buttons** on the page in an array, with that you can loop through and access properties of individual button eg. **name**

So we use this instead **var x = document.getElementsByTagName("button")** which returns an array of buttons on the page.

That being said, let's see how we can modify your code to achieve what you're looking for:

HTML:

```
 <button type="button" name="Tom" onclick="buttonBgColor(event)"> Tom</button>
 <button type="button" name="Dick" onclick="buttonBgColor(event)"> DicK </button>
 <button type="button" name="Harry" onclick="buttonBgColor(event)"> Harry </button>
```

JS:

```
   function buttonBgColor(e) {
     const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button").name;

      for(button of buttons){

         const current_button = e.target;

          if(current_button.name == 'Tom'){
            current_button.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgray'
          }else if(current_button.name == 'Dick'){
            current_button.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen'
          }else if(current_button.name == 'Harry'){
            current_button.style.backgroundColor = 'lightyellow'
          }
      }
    }
```

This method is useful because assuming you have two **buttons** with same name say **'Tom'** and yet you want one of them to do something extra aside changing their background colors, you can reference their **ID** to achieve that using **e.target.id or current_button.id** in a condition to wire up another handler for that particular **'Tom' button**.

Hope this helps.